# Is there a specific name for this process?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Problem Statement:

> You have 9 dollars. The store sells sandwiches for 5 dollars, drinks for 3 dollars, and chips for 1 dollar. If you want to spend all of your money and exit the store with the least amount of items, how much of each item should you get?

I understand the concept, obviously you should get 1 sandwich, 1 drink, and 1 bag of chips.
but is there a name for that process?

9/5 = 1 r4

4/3 = 1 r1

1/1 = 1 r0

Is there an easier way to implement this while coding, for any general values of the initial amount and the item prices?

Comment: This is the [change-making problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgiZlGzXMBw), which, so far as I can see, has nothing at all to do with modular arithmetic.

Comment: @saulspatz what would you put this problem under then?